# What causes a vehicle to catch on fire?

Tags: h3, hummer

About a month ago I went to get my trans coolant hoses replaced. I was told that they were leaking. So on Saturday (5/13/17) my H3 caught a fire under the hood. The fire was at the bottom on the right hand side of my vehicle. Transmission fluid was everywhere. The  fire went out by itself. I was thankful of that. Do you think this has something to do with this repair of the hoses? If so, if there is further damage to my vehicle, can that mechanic be responsible?

Comment: Needs to be inspected - the fire could be from something else and the transmission hoses got burnt causing the loss of fluid. Without inspection - anybody's guess...

Comment: my first though on under hood fire would be to look for an electrical source. Starter motor harness for example.  Of course regardless of the source its always possible the tech damaged something doing the cooler hose job, but also tough to prove.

Comment: Did you actually see fire by the way? I'd expect trans fluid leaking onto something hot like the exhaust manifold to produce a lot of smoke, but not actually catch fire.